# PHP - Unique fields not recognized

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Today when I was creating a system through which user can register I tried to create a field in which an id can be registered only once. But when I ran the code , It's not working. Please help.

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM voter WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {

    echo "<script>alert('Voter ID already exists.')</script>";

}
```

Comment: For a UX point of view, script.alert isn't an elegant way to provide messages to your users.

Comment: You can't tell us "it's not working". You have to tell us HOW it is not working. You think someone will run the code you posted? If something doesn't work, include the error or if there are no errors - how it's supposed behave and how it behaves.

Comment: [Don't use mysql_query.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: OK I'll try to echo this message

Comment: You must use PDO or mysqli insted of mysql functions

Comment: Sorry but due I don't have reputations I can't post images

Comment: Check http://www.voteindia.tk

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM voter WHERE id = '{$id}'";
```

Also remeber that the id column should be an INTEGER. And are your sure the $id var is set?

Comment: I can't find anything useful on that page to answer your question, what do you want me to see? Also, report your errors like this: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, it will make things alot easier.

Comment: On this website ID is a unique field and others are just normal. When I try to register a user with same voter ID again, instead of showing the error, It says registration succeessful. This result is not expected

Comment: First, add this line of PHP to see if any errors occur: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Second, I don't see any code except the code in your first post, which should work if you change the query into what I told you. Post more information/code so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: The insert statement has the same problem as I explained in my answer. Change it to: `$sql = "INSERT INTO voter(name, address, id, fpass, spass, tpass) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$address}', '{$id}', '{$pass1}', '{$pass2}', '{$pass3}')";` Check your database and see if the correct values are being inserted into the table.